# Weak entity with 2 different owner entities

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

Weak entity with 2 owner entities

I have a database I am trying to design with 3 entities: Store, Item, and Wishlist. Stores and Wishlists exist on their own, and are therefore strong. Items, however, will not exist unless they are either in stock at a store or on someone's wishlist.

What's the best practice in designing the ER diagram ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is really two one-many relationships with an extra constraint on participation ("must be in stock or on a wishlist"). This does not mean that an Item is a weak entity type. I think Item in this case must be strong. I don't think there is any standard ER notation for a participation constraint across mutiple entities unless the entities are all subtypes. I suggest you add a text notation to the diagram if it's important to explain that an item must either be in stock or on a wishlist but doesn't have to be both.

It is sometimes said that a weak entity cannot exist independently of a related entity. That alone is not what makes something weak however. An entity type is weak if it does not have its own *identifier* independent of another entity type. In your situation I would expect that an item could appear on more than one wishlist or be stocked in more than one store and therefore items must have a common identifier (e.g. a name or a UPC) independently of the wishlists and stores that include them. If that was not the case then wishlist items and stock would presumably have to be subtypes of item, which seems a bit unconventional.

If for some reason you did want to treat items of stock and items on wishlists as subtypes of items then the answer to your question would be a subtype relationship with mandatory participation, e.g. represented with double lines using Chen notation:

[image: subtypes with mandatory participation]